# Weird error after Perl upgrade: Unable to flush stdout

Tags: perl, runtime-error, warnings

After upgrading to Perl 5.24.4 we repeatedly get this error in logs (without pointing the filename and line number):

> Unable to flush stdout: Broken pipe

We have no idea what causes this error.

Is there any advice how to understand the cause of the error?

Comment: what is your `shebang` top of your script?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard We have hundreds, maybe thousands of scripts. The main problem is that it's unknown which script causes the error. Shebangs are `#!/usr/bin/perl` or `#!/usr/local/bin/perl`. Symlink `/usr/bin/perl -> /usr/local/bin/perl`

Comment: and your new perl version is at this location? If it is, then I will delete my comments, just trying to figure possible reasons.

Comment: How did you upgrade perl?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard The new perl is at the same location as before.

Comment: @Borodin I suppose our system admin installed a new version of FreeBSD perl package

Comment: Verify the name of the file as being `perl` and not something like `perl5..`

Comment: @porton: You can't just install a new perl on top of the old one; it sounds like you need to delete everything and reinstall from scratch. But if the sysop did the upgrade then it's their job to fix it.

Answer (score 5):

The error comes from [perl.c, line 595](https://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/v5.24.4:/perl.c#l595):

```c
        PerlIO_printf(PerlIO_stderr(), "Unable to flush stdout: %s",
                      Strerror(errno));
```

This line is part of [`perl_destruct`](https://perldoc.pl/perlapi#perl_destruct), which is called to shut down the perl interpreter at the end of the program.

As part of the global shutdown procedure, all still open filehandles are flushed (i.e. all buffered output is written out). The comment above says:

```c
 /* Need to flush since END blocks can produce output */
 /* flush stdout separately, since we can identify it */
```

The error message is not listed in [`perldoc perldiag`](https://perldoc.pl/perldiag), which is arguably a documentation bug. It was probably overlooked because it's not a real `warn` or `die` call, it's effectively just `print STDERR $message`. It's not associated with a file name or line number because it only happens after your program stops running (i.e. after a call to `exit` or because execution fell off the end of the main script).

Answer (score 2):

This is very general advice, but

```
use Carp::Always;
```

at the top of the script, or running with

```
perl -MCarp::Always the_script.pl arg1 arg2 ...
```

will get Perl to produce stack traces with every warning and error.

Comment: Great advice, but it won't help in this case. [This is neither a warning nor an exception.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52106594/589924)

Comment: You can avoid overriding the shebang line by using `PERL5OPT=-MCarp::Always the_script.pl arg1 arg2 ...`

Answer (score 2):

`Broken pipe` is the error string associated with system error `EPIPE`. One receives this error when writing to a closed pipe. Writing to a closed pipe usally results in the process being killed by a SIGPIPE, so it means the behaviour of SIGPIPE was changed from its default.

```
$ perl -e'
   $SIG{PIPE} = "IGNORE";
   print "foo\n"
      or die("Can\x27t write to STDOUT: $!\n");
   sleep(2);
   close(STDOUT)
      or die("Unable to flush STDOUT: $!\n");
' | perl -e'sleep(1)'
Unable to flush STDOUT: Broken pipe
```

As melpomene [discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52106594/589924), the error is automatically output if you write to a broken pipe in an `END` block.

```
$ perl -e'
   $SIG{PIPE} = "IGNORE";
   sleep(2);
   END { print "foo\n"; }
' | perl -e'sleep(1)'
Unable to flush stdout: Broken pipe
```

This isn't necessarily a problem, although it could be a sign that a process is exiting prematurely.

Comment: It can be simplified: `perl -e '$SIG{PIPE} = "IGNORE"; sleep(1); print "foo\n";' | echo -n` is a short code which produces this error