# How to cause "Unable to flush stdout: Broken pipe" in Perl?

Tags: runtime-error, warnings, perl

Please provide me a minimal Perl example which produces this error:

> Unable to flush stdout: Broken pipe

See also [Weird error after Perl upgrade: Unable to flush stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50507849/856090)

Comment: Your linked question provides an example. Redirect STDOUT to a file, and reproduce the problem described in the link.

Comment: @bytepusher, Re "*Redirect STDOUT to a file*", You can't get `EPIPE` from writing to a file; you can only get it from writing to a pipe or socket.

Comment: Fair enough! My comment is out of date anyhow given you've answered the question, but thanks for clearing that up :)

Comment: Sorry, I noticed it is indeed answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/52139990/856090

Comment: `perl -e '$SIG{PIPE} = "IGNORE"; sleep(1); print "foo\n";' | echo -n` is the answer